# Why are IDs showing in URLs when clean URLs are enabled?

Tags: path-aliases

I've enabled clean URLs on my site, and currently, URLs are of the form:

> /node/123

How can I force them to to use human-readable URLs? Something like:

> /node/title-of-node

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Clean URLs setting turns your URLs from `index.php?q=node/123` to `/node/123`.

The path module that comes with core Drupal enables the `URL path settings` tab on node add/edit forms. Here you can specify **any** URL alias that will load the node instead of `/node/123`. These aliases must be entered manually for each node.

The [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module allows you to automatically generate URL aliases. By enabling pathauto and not doing any further configuration your URLs will turn into `/content/title-of-node`. You can change how the URL is generated in the pathauto settings (so it can be `/node/title-of-node` for example).

Comment: Pathauto is the answer. Use it to auto assign names. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what reported by rocketeerbkw, I will suggest you to check also the [Sub-path URL Aliases](http://drupal.org/project/subpath_alias) module (Drupal 6) or the [Sub-pathauto (Sub-path URL Aliases)](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module (Drupal 7). The Pathauto module creates the aliases for URLs like example.com/node/1, or example-com/user/1; it doesn't create a path alias for example.com/node/1/edit, for example, and the  purpose of those modules is to allow using the path alias also for example.com/node/1/edit, which would become example.com/node_alias_1/edit, where node_alias_1 is the alias for node/1.

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias.
>
> For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead. This also includes Views URLs taking a node as argument (e.g. node/%/yourview), in short, every URL that is based on, or extends, an existing alias. In combination with the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module it is possible to get rid of all remaining exposed internal non-administrative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If path module is enabled, you can change URLs in admin/config/search/path.
Or you can change the URL alias directly when adding new content in URL path settings field.